# "Kosher"switch, is it really kosher?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, rabbis, melacha-creative-work

So I am wondering if it is acceptable or not, breaking shabbes or not, and I want to see what the Big rabbonim have to say about the "Kosher"switch.

Comment: What is this kosher switch of which you speak? Is it the same one discussed in [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60171/kosher-murder-switch) and [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57605/kosher-switch-and-grama-according-to-r-belskys-letter)?

Comment: By the way, if you [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) you can gain access to a bunch of neat features.

Comment: Rabbi Nissan Kaplan has a shiur on this. he says its not at all kosher http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/aud/5775-Halacha/017-kosher_electric_switch.mp3